# External Display Resolution

Tags: display, resolution

I am running OS X El Capitan on a 15" Retina display MBP and I recently hooked up an external monitor (Samsung SyncMasterP2370HD) via an HDMI cable. The font is weirdly pixelated at any resolution available *except* 1600x1200 which I got by doing the force RGB work around. Unfortunately at that resolution everything is stretched wide. While I can handle the ugly font right now with 1080p and some underscan (I switched the profile back from the forced RGB to the default), I was hoping there was a work around which allowed me to pick whatever resolution my heart desires (I know the option + click "Scaled" trick, the ones I'm looking for aren't available).

So is there a terminal command I can use to change the resolution on my external? If not, is there something else I can do? I'd like to at least *try* to see what the display looks like at say 1680x1050.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENDS UP - the answer is to change the name of the HDMI input through the display's menu (the samsung menu from the external) to PC or DVI PC.

Answer from here: https://superuser.com/questions/146841/why-does-text-look-so-horrible-on-my-hd-monitor. Apparently I was searching on the wrong stackexchange.

Comment: If you solved your own question be sure to accept your answer. This will help others would might have a similar problem.